# How to add multiple text on xaxis

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, sankey-diagram

I am struggling with adding multiple texts on the x-axis. Most of the things like giving name field in x-axis don't work with Sankey diagram.

Problem: I need to add 2 texts just below my x-axis on my Sankey diagram. The first text just below and center of the blue bar. The second text I need just below gray bar but it should be in the same line with respect to first text

Here is my code

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    title: {
        text: ''
    },
        xAxis: {
        type: 'football league'
    },

    series: [{
        keys: ['from', 'to', 'weight'],
        data: [
            ['Football', 'Messi', 20 ],
            ['Football', 'ronaldo', 3 ],
            //['Challenged', 'Terminated', 0 ],
            ['Football', 'sachin', 1 ],
            ['Messi', 'sehqag', 12 ],
            //['Instituted', ' Terminated', 0 ],
            ['Messi', 'ashwin', 6 ],
            ['Messi', ' ramesg', 2 ],

        ],
        type: 'sankey',
        name: 'Sankey demo series'
    }]

});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/anikettiwari/kLzv8sp0/26/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this by below code

```
 chart: {
      showAxes: true
    },
     xAxis: {
          categories: ['ANIKET','SHivam'],
          labels: {
            style: {
              color: '#000000'
            }
          }
        },
        yAxis: {
          title: '',
          labels: {
            formatter: function() {
              return '';
            },
            style: {
              color: '#4572A7'
            }
          }
        },
```

For the y-axis it was giving me default label so for removing it I wrote the above yaxis code

Answer (score 1):

To add text to the chart, you can use **annotations** module or **Highcharts.SVGRenderer**:

```
annotations: [{
    labels: [{
        text: 'annotations',
        point: {
            x: 100,
            y: 380
        }
    }, {
        text: 'annotations2',
        point: {
            x: 400,
            y: 380
        }
    }]
}]
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/odc4jsku/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#text

Docs: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/annotations-module

Comment: Thanks for the help btw I found the solution